# can't upload signed apk/appBundle to play dev accoun "integrity check failed"

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I keep getting this error while trying to upload a signed apk/app bundle to the google developer account

```
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (APK Signature Scheme v2 signer #0): APK integrity check failed. CHUNKED_SHA256 digest mismatch. Expected: <c19f74fd98ea620a8a227db0aa9c4156b6b48cc1c3b09f5699180376108394e2>, actual: <d623a2882a89665d6a1e31107a43e0e3204ff567f4f44a2058dbfc8a5217edea>
```

I can't understand the reason behind this error.

Comment: I think you built an apk and then signed it. Try flutter clean then flutter build apk release . Should work

Comment: thanks, it is working now. I did flutter clean then flutter build appbundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run:

```
flutter clean
```

to delete the build folder
and then:

```
flutter build appbundle
```

to create the appbundle, and it is working just fine. But from the Android Studio GUI it's not working for some reason.